# How tor rebase only one component in stream using CLEARTOOL?

Tags: clearcase

Using ClerCase ver. 8

I would like to rebase only component GUI to a previous baseline, i.e. '8.107.22.168.2726' **using cleartool**. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Please mention the exact issue or error message that prevents you to rebase to the expected baseline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `DUATB1_latest` stream is an integration stream, that is: the main stream of an UCM project, you should be able to chose whatever baseline you want from the GUI component in order to change the baseline.

Use an UCM dynamic view associated to that stream, and [cleartool rebase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm)

```
cd /path/to/dynamic/view
cleartool rebase -bas 8.107.22.168.2726
cleartool rebase -complete
```

If that stream is a substream however, you cannot change its baseline (unless it comes directly from the parent stream): you would need to deliver that baseline (from its original stream to your current stream). That would not change the foundation baseline but at least it would merge that older baseline into your stream.

Comment: VonC - as you are a ClearCase expert, can you please also look at this related question I just posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568310/rebasing-a-clearcase-stream-with-cleartool-produces-pop-up-screen.